# Which element will be stored in which bucket?

Tags: hash, collections, hashset

I have a HashMap implemented and giving this output (Output1)
Can you please explain which element will be stored in which bucket.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Dog
{
    public int i;
    public int hashCode()
        {
            return i+3; // hashcode1
        }
    Dog(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return i +  "" ;
    }

}
class ShellClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        HashSet s = new HashSet(5,(float)0.8);
        for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
        {
            s.add((new Dog(i)));
        }


        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
Output1 : [1, 2, 3, 4] //with hashcode1
```

However if hashcode is changed to following:

```
public int hashCode()
{
            return i%3; //hashCode2
}
```

Output changes to :

```
Output2: [3, 1, 4, 2] //with hashcode2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HashSet documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) does not guarantee any particular order for how elements are returned by its iterator. It seems reasonable to infer that its toString method does not guarantee any particular order either.

Thus, to predict which element would be stored in which bucket would require knowledge of the source code for the particular HashSet implementation you are using (which depends on which standard library implementation your Java runtime links to, but its likely to be Oracle's).

(We need knowledge of the source code *in addition to* the current capacity and load factor for the particular hash set, but you are providing that information in your constructor invocation, so I guess we can assume that is a given.)

Anyway, you can see the [source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.indexFor%28int%2Cint%29). (Its actually the source code for `HashMap`, but that is what `HashSet` uses underneath the hood.)

The way it works, it computes a bucket index from the hashcode `h` and the  (presumably positive) table length `l` via the expression `h & (l-1)`. Why does it need to do this? Well, the hashcode `h` for arbitrary objects is not necessarily within the range of the length of the table; this `&`-expression will ensure that the resulting index *is* in the range of the table length.

So as you modify the hashCode computation in your own class, it changes the computed index generated via `h & (l-1)`.

(Caveat: The value for `h` may not actually be the *direct* result from invoking `hashCode`. In particular, the `HashMap` implementation has a helper method `hash` that takes the result of `hashCode` and transforms it in a deterministic way to a different number.)

---

*Very* Important Note: There is a contract that *all* Java classes are supposed to uphold: The interface defined by `java.lang.Object`. In particular, there is a [rule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) defined by the docs for `Object`: "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result." (This is actually just one part of a multi-part rule described there.)

Your code is actually adhering to this rule, because you have not overridden the `equals` method, and so you are inheriting the default one, which implements the "most discriminating possible equivalence relation." But if you were to override `equals` yourself, you would be obliged to ensure that your code for `equals` is consistent with your code for `hashCode`.

---

(Exercise for the reader: If `l` is a number like 3, the expression `h & (l-1)` always gives either the result 0 or 2, depending on the value of `h`. This would miss the potential entry at index 1, thus wasting space within the table. Wasted space sounds like a bad thing; does the [linked implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.indexFor%28int%2Cint%29) actually suffer from this hypothetical problem?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer pnkfelix.
In case of Hashtable, I assume that bucket is calculated based on (hashcode value returned by hashcode method  % length of Hashtable) and then output of toString is the sequence of these buckets from top to bottom and right to left in a single bucket. It always gives fine result. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Hi shubh; if my answer resolved your question, then please accept the answer. That way other people do not think this question needs an alternative answer. :)

Comment: Regarding the assumption of whether the bucket is calculated based on `hashCode() % length`, I respond with: Is that the same as doing `h & (l-1)`, as I already showed in the source? Lets see, what if `h=4` and `l=3` ... then `h%l` is `4%3` = `1`, while `h & (l-1)` is `4 & (3-1)` = `0`. So they aren't the same in all possible cases, it seems... but maybe you are on to something nonetheless? I recommend you look into my "Exercise for the reader" for more on this...

Comment: More generally, as a matter of good coding practices, I'd say its probably *not* a good idea to make assumptions about order of elements returned in the `toString` encoding. (The first two paragraphs of my answer were meant to strongly imply this, but I worry from shubh's comment that I was too subtle.)  I would say that if you are somehow relying on a particular ordering, then you probably want to use a different hashtable implementation that will actually guarantee a stable ordering in its specification. HashMap and HashSet explicitly do not do this.